# Rectangle does not contain a constructor that takes 4 arguments

Tags: c#

I have a problem that I am creating a rectangle in a picturebox through PictureBox1_Paint() event but when we call the constructor of Rectangle class it shows an error as Rectangle class does not contain a constructor that takes 4 arguments, I don't know how to resolve this and also where I go wrong? Please suggest me for the right solution regarding the same.

**Code:**

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle ee = new Rectangle(10, 10, 30, 30);

    using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2))
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, ee);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using System.Drawing and not System.Windows.Shapes?

Answer (score 6):

Probably you included a namespace (through the [`using` directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) at the very beginning of your .CS file) that includes a `Rectangle` class/structure that has the same name but otherwise is non-related to the [`Rectangle` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle.aspx).

Try the absolute name like:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    System.Drawing.Rectangle ee = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(10, 10, 30, 30);

    using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2))
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, ee);
    }
}
```

I.e. use `System.Drawing.Rectangle` instead of just `Rectangle`.